# how to get different workspace corresponding to project selection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on eclipse plugin. In project explorer there are several projects and i have store those projects in different Workspace (i have add new project but different workspace). For getting selected project's workspace, i use following code

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

but it always returns the workspace that i have selected when i open project first time. Is there any way to get different workspace corresponding to different project selection from project explorer.

Comment: Projects are always in the current workspace so you can't 'add new project but different workspace'. What did you actually do?

Comment: simple i go through file->new->project-> <select project type> -> uncheck <use default project location> and browse new location, enter project name ->finish     so therefore i have different projects from different workspace but in same project explorer

Comment: The Project is still created in the current workspace but with references to files which are in a different location.

Comment: but i am not able to find that project path. Is there any way to find these reference project physical path.

Comment: Even though you've added a project from a different workspace, that will just act as a project folder. There will be only one workspace. i.e ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() , but you can get the project location using currentselection.getProject().getLocation() will return the actual project location.

Comment: @KondalKolipaka "currenselection" is object of which class?

Answer (score 1):

In your project selection listener, you can do something like this. I hope you're referring to standard eclipse project explorer.

```
ISelectionService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();
    IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
    if (structured instanceof IStructuredSelection)
    {
        Object selectedObject = ((IStructuredSelection) structured).getFirstElement();
        if (selectedObject instanceof IAdaptable)
        {
            IResource resource = (IResource) ((IAdaptable) selectedObject).getAdapter(IResource.class);
            if (resource != null)
            {
                IProject project = resource.getProject();
                 IPath location = project.getLocation();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All Projects are created in the current workspace. Eclipse never has more  that one workspace active at a time.

If you create a project using a different location you can see that in the project location.

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IProject project = root.getProject("Project");

IPath pathInWorkspace = project.getFullPath();

IPath actualLocation = project.getLocation();
```

Replace "Project" with the name of your project, or find the project from the selection.

`pathInWorkspace` is the workspace relative path and would just be `/Project` in this case.

`actualLocation` is the actual location of the project in the file system.

Comment: i am getting "/Poject" value from pathInWorkspace and null from actualLocation

Comment: i need to get corresponding path whenever i select project

Comment: "Project" should be the name of your project.